# PowerMockito call private method that throws Exception fails

Tags: java, mockito, powermock

I try to mock following method `foo` in class `MyClass`:

```
private Class<?> foo(final String str) throws ClassNotFoundException{
    return Class.forName(str);
}
```

So I wrote:

```
MyClass pl = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());

try {
    PowerMockito.when(pl, PowerMockito.method(MyClass.class, "foo", String.class))
                .withArguments(anyString())
                .thenReturn(Boolean.TRUE.getClass());
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // catch ClassNotFoundException
}
```

It doesn't work and throws Exception `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`.

However, if i'll replace `return Class.forName(str)` with `return  Boolean.TRUE.getClass();` in `foo` method - everything is ok.

How to tell to `PowerMockito` to invoke method `foo` that throws Exception on failure?

Answer (score 0):

1. if you dont need real method call , and you can work with mock - change spy() to mock()

MyClass pl = PowerMockito.**spy(new MyClass())**;

MyClass pl = PowerMockito.**mock(MyClass.claa)**;

and your code works without any changes , except spy/mock.

2. if you need **SPY()** with real method call

do this:

MyClass pl = PowerMockito.spy(new MyClass());

```
    try {
        PowerMockito.doReturn(Boolean.TRUE.getClass())
                .when(pl, PowerMockito.method(MyClass.class, "foo", String.class))
                .withArguments(anyString());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); // catch ClassNotFoundException
    }
```

---

> However, if i'll replace return Class.forName(str) with return 
>   Boolean.TRUE.getClass(); in foo method - everything is ok.

this works due to 1. it's call a real metho , 2. you retrun Boolean class . but when you call with anyString() it calls real method and pass null as value.

read [Important gotcha on spying real objects!](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/1.10.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#spy) :):)